# 3D Input layer Keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

I have a 3D input layer to my model and I am trying to encode each 2D input separately. My context input contains 10 turns each of size 50.

```
context_input = Input(shape=(10, 50), dtype='int32')
```

and I have a Turn encoder that encodes a turn separately. I want to do

```
turn_1_branch = turn_encoder(context_input[0])
```

how can I do this ?